# Get Spring view without mapping a Controller to a URL pattern

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to create a method just like a Controller method, but without mapping it to a request pattern, as it should be called from another piece of code.

The method will take some parameters and, probably, populate the model.

Basically I want Spring MVC to do the job of merging model with the view jsp, and, probably, print it to the HttpServletResponse that I provide and set some other headers like Spring will normally do.

Should be a few lines of code but I can't imagine which:)

Answer (score 1):

You can try ViewControllerRegistry to generated the view without using the controller.

Please check the example bellow. I am using java based configration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean  
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {  
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();  
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");  
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;  
    }
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("myhome");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("helloworld");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/home", "/hello");
        registry.addStatusController("/detail", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);        
    }    
}
```

My myhome.jsp file would be

```
<html>
<head><title>Home Page</title></head>
<body>
   <h3> Home Page </h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still maps the view to a url; I understand that my caption "without a controller" is misleading, let me change that to "without mapping a controller to a url pattern"